# Make phone call android and get number from edittext box

Tags: android, phone-call

How do I make a phone call when I get number from edittext? I try this but it does not work. I have a problem with passing variable number to Uri.parse() must be inside void the gettext?

```
public String string;
public String number;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


     EditText txtcallnumber;
     txtcallnumber = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.callnumber);
     string = txtcallnumber.getText().toString().trim();//There no work call
       number = "tel:" + string;

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
          call();
        }
      });
}


public void call() {
try {
   Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    //callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:xxxxxxx")); //This work
    string = txtcallnumber.getText().toString().trim();
       number = "tel:" + string;//There work call
    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse(number));
    startActivity(callIntent);


} catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
     Log.e("helloandroid dialing example", "Call failed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Permission inside in your manifest file ::

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE">
```

Inside your call() method try to use these Intent::

```
number=edittext.getText().trim();
no="tel:"+number;

startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(no)));
```

Comment: @user1909897 what do mean by "inside void?"

Comment: @user1909897 your way was absolute right but ACTION_CALL needs permission that's why you are getting security error in your log.

Comment: @user1909897 adding ACTION_DIAL doesn't require any permission so try to replace ACTION_CALL with ACTION_DIAL without permission in your original code. It definitely works.

Comment: I have permissions ok...but the number=edittext.getText().trim();
no="tel:"+number; why must be inside intent for work ....no work on Create...

Comment: It's okay to put no="tel:"+number wherever you want. Just put it before the variable "no" used in your code. It's perfectly fine if you put inside onCreate()

Comment: Maybe because i have try catch?

Comment: Yeah, May be try using your try-catch block :)

Answer (score 0):

in onCreate method there is no need for :

```
 string = txtcallnumber.getText().toString().trim();
 number = "tel:" + string;
```

because onCreate is pretty much used for setting up the display and there will be no input by the user before the screen is set up but in onCall method after entering the text and pressing the button then it wouldd...you know.

Plus you should have this to check for nothing entered:

```
if(string!=null){
  try{try {
Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);

string = txtcallnumber.getText().toString().trim();
   number = "tel:" + string;
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse(number)));


} catch (ActivityNotFoundException activityException) {
 Log.e("helloandroid dialing example", "Call failed");

      }}else{
    Log.d("helloandroid dialing example","nothing entered");}
```